# Magento 2: Send admin email template programmatically

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

I have created an email template for my custom form as follows:

```
Vendor/Module/etc/email_templates.xml

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:Magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="custom_email_template" label="Warranty Email" file="custom_email_template.html" type="html" module="Vendor_Module" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

and created the template file in

```
app/design/frontent/Vendor/Theme/Vendor_Module/email/custom_email_template.html
```

Now when I create a new template in Marketing -> Email templates I am able to see my new created template in the dropdown. I put the content for the template and save it in admin. But when the email is sent, it is sent from the custom_email_template.html content and not the content from the admin template.

I am sending email programmatically as follows:

```
$this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $sender = [
            'name' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml('Sufyan Khot'),
            'email' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml('sufyan.khot@gmail.com'),
        ];
        $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                        ->setTemplateIdentifier('custom_email_template')
                        ->setTemplateOptions(
                            [
                                'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                                'store' => 2,
                            ]
                        )
                        ->setTemplateVars([
                            'templateVar'  => 'Custom email',
                        ])
                        ->setFrom($sender)
                        ->addTo('sufyan.khot@gmail.com')
                        ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
```

You can see I have put the template id as `custom_email_template` as specified in `email_template.xml`. When I check in the database I cannot find any column for email template I created in admin.

**I want to send the content from the email template created in admin and not from the html file.**

Answer (score 0):

add your content of email templates in app/design/frontent/Vendor/Theme/Vendor_Module/email/custom_email_template.html

Answer (score 0):

Try Checking this template in email marketing templates in Magento admin. But first create a demo content HTML template in this location.

> add your content of email templates in
> app/design/frontent/Vendor/Theme/Vendor_Module/email/custom_email_template.html